# Xdebug does not generate the log file

Tags: apache, ubuntu-18.04, xdebug, profiler, php-7.2

Please help me ! i'm going crazy, i don't understand! **xdebug doesn't generate the log file for Kcachegrind.**

**Please do you have an idea or a solution ?**

**Environment:**
Ubuntu 18.04
PHP Version 7.2.34-8+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1apache
Apache Version  Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu)

I run a script with the url: https://myUrlScript.com/fr/xdebugtest.php

Below is my php.ini file.

My file /etc/php/**7.2**/mods-available/xdebug.ini

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension="/usr/lib/php/20170718/xdebug.so"
xdebug.profiler_enable=1
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger=0
xdebug.profiler_output_name=cachegrind.out.%s
xdebug.profiler_output_dir=/var/log/xdebug/
```

My phpinfo()

```
Support Xdebug on Patreon, GitHub, or as a business: https://xdebug.org/support
xdebug.auto_trace => no value => no value
xdebug.cli_color => 0 => 0
xdebug.client_discovery_header => no value => no value
xdebug.client_host => localhost => localhost
xdebug.client_port => 9003 => 9003
xdebug.cloud_id => no value => no value
xdebug.collect_assignments => Off => Off
xdebug.collect_includes => no value => no value
xdebug.collect_params => no value => no value
xdebug.collect_return => Off => Off
xdebug.collect_vars => no value => no value
xdebug.connect_timeout_ms => 200 => 200
xdebug.coverage_enable => no value => no value
xdebug.default_enable => no value => no value
xdebug.discover_client_host => Off => Off
xdebug.dump.COOKIE => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.ENV => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.FILES => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.GET => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.POST => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.REQUEST => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.SERVER => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.SESSION => no value => no value
xdebug.dump_globals => On => On
xdebug.dump_once => On => On
xdebug.dump_undefined => Off => Off
xdebug.extended_info => no value => no value
xdebug.file_link_format => no value => no value
xdebug.filename_format => no value => no value
xdebug.force_display_errors => Off => Off
xdebug.force_error_reporting => 0 => 0
xdebug.gc_stats_enable => no value => no value
xdebug.gc_stats_output_dir => no value => no value
xdebug.gc_stats_output_name => gcstats.%p => gcstats.%p
xdebug.halt_level => 0 => 0
xdebug.idekey => no value => no value
xdebug.log => no value => no value
xdebug.log_level => 7 => 7
xdebug.max_nesting_level => 256 => 256
xdebug.max_stack_frames => -1 => -1
xdebug.mode => develop => develop
xdebug.output_dir => /tmp => /tmp
xdebug.overload_var_dump => no value => no value
xdebug.profiler_append => Off => Off
xdebug.profiler_enable => 1 => 1
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger => no value => no value
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger_value => no value => no value
xdebug.profiler_output_dir => /var/log/xdebug/ => /var/log/xdebug/
xdebug.profiler_output_name => cachegrind.out.%s => cachegrind.out.%s
xdebug.remote_autostart => no value => no value
xdebug.remote_connect_back => no value => no value
xdebug.remote_enable => no value => no value
xdebug.remote_handler => no value => no value
xdebug.remote_host => no value => no value
xdebug.remote_log => no value => no value
xdebug.remote_log_level => no value => no value
xdebug.remote_mode => no value => no value
xdebug.remote_port => no value => no value
xdebug.remote_timeout => no value => no value
xdebug.scream => Off => Off
xdebug.show_error_trace => Off => Off
xdebug.show_exception_trace => Off => Off
xdebug.show_local_vars => Off => Off
xdebug.show_mem_delta => no value => no value
xdebug.start_upon_error => default => default
xdebug.start_with_request => default => default
xdebug.trace_enable_trigger => no value => no value
xdebug.trace_enable_trigger_value => no value => no value
xdebug.trace_format => 0 => 0
xdebug.trace_options => 0 => 0
xdebug.trace_output_dir => no value => no value
xdebug.trace_output_name => trace.%c => trace.%c
xdebug.trigger_value => no value => no value
xdebug.var_display_max_children => 128 => 128
xdebug.var_display_max_data => 512 => 512
xdebug.var_display_max_depth => 3 => 3
OLDPWD => /var/log/xdebug
$_SERVER['OLDPWD'] => /var/log/xdebug
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What log file? ... the xdebug setting for the log shows: `xdebug.log => no value => no value`

Comment: This file  xdebug.profiler_output_name=cachegrind.out.%s is not in the folder /var/log/xdebug/

Comment: @screem How did you get this `phpinfo()` output? Was it from terminal (e.g. `php -i` will print the same) or was it gathered from a browser (by calling a page with `phpinfo()` via URL)? The text is typical for CLI output... Thing is: on Linux & Mac it's very common to have separate php.ini for CLI and web server. Having Xdebug enabled in one does not necessarily mean that it will be enabled in another environment (you can look at phpinfo() top table output -- it will list what master and other .ini files were used). Double check that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve the problem, I installed the old version of xdebug. I had version 3.0.0beta with php 7.2, so I installed version 2.9.2 of xdebug and no more problems.

Comment: I also inadvertently installed the beta version too. How do I downgrade on a remote Linux server via command line? I'm not super strong in that area– I installed with `sudo apt-get install php-xdebug`